# Apache DNS Resolves Slow on Route53 Configuration

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I am able to access my site but it appears DNS isn't being resolved correctly, meaning it takes forever for the site to be found. Once its located the site performs as expected, but if I were to wait a few minutes and try to retrieve the site once more, it again takes a long time (20+secs) to resolve. This is for production, and not a local development. Note: If I go to to my servers elastic IP (54.245.124.102) my site loads instantly.

**Route 53**

```
 NAME: example.com.
 TYPE: A
 VALUE: 54.215.114.102  -  10.252.55.133
 TTL: 7200

 NAME: example.com.
 TYPE: NS
 VALUE: ns-1043.awsdns-12.org. - ns-1709.awsdns-11.co.uk. 
 TTL: 7200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was experiencing was that there was a coin flip chance of getting either IP address. 10net(10.x.x.x) IP addresses are not routeable over the internet, people outside of my local network could reach the 10net address. This was causing dns resolution times to be slow.